# Change location.hash on unbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload, hashchange

I have a page which is generated using JavaScript. I want to store the `$(window).scrollTop()` value in a hash (like `#position=xxx`) so when the page is refreshed and the items are generated again, the user can continue scrolling from where they left off.

I'm trying to modify the hash on `beforeunload`, which does not seem to work. The first part of the function below tries to change the hash, and the second part is taking care of the modification of the scrollTop on page load. The second part works fine, I'm only stuck with the first part.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload',function(){
    window.location.hash = "position="+$(window).scrollTop();
}).on('load hashchange',function(){
    var scrollregex = /^position=(\d+)$/,
        hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    if (scrollregex.test(hash)) $(window).scrollTop(parseInt(hash.match(scrollregex)[1]));
});
```

Is there a different event for this, or otherwise how can I change the hash when the user triggers a refresh?

Comment: Looks like you want to use some persistent data client side which is not the purpose of hash but cookies or local/session storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up ditching the hash idea and going with a `sessionStorage` based approach. I wrote [my own wrapper](https://gist.github.com/SeinopSys/6596c30d04bac1184a3b) for session/local storage which I use in the following example.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload',function(){
    var scrltop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrltop > 0) SStorage.set('position',scrltop);
    else SStorage.del('position');
}).on('load',function(){
    if (SStorage.has('position')){
        var pos = parseInt(SStorage.get('position'));
        if (!isNaN(pos) && $(window).scrollTop() === 0) $(window).scrollTop(pos);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome doesn't seem to allow you to update the hash in the onbeforeunload event. I had a similar issue. I moved my code to the unload event, which worked but introduced other issues. To solve them I have to force a reload, note reload will not work without the setTimeout.

```
$(window).on('unload', function(){ 
    /* Do hash change here */

    setTimeout(function () { window.location.reload(true); }, 0); 
});
```

Comment: Doing a hash change on `unload` seems to break all links on the page. I don't think this could be a working solution, but it does, however, allows changing of the hash.

Comment: Yes I found some odd behaviour myself altering adding the hash, it seemed to kill my JavaScript. That's why I added the force reload. This is the solution I've been working with shame it didn't work for you.